# TSQL Sort Data not Working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a piece of a query that is used in a dynamic SQL statement. In this case, it is taking a list of selected fields, their orders, and sorting preference so creating the `SORT` statement.

```
-- Insert the data into the sort statements
INSERT into @sortStatements (sortStatement)
SELECT fo.fieldName + ' ' + b.FilterValues
FROM red.dbo.BS_ContentRequests_Tasks_User_Fields AS a
JOIN red.dbo.BS_ContentRequests_Tasks_Fields_Options AS fo
ON a.fieldID = fo.fieldID
JOIN (
    Select Main.fieldID, Left(Main.FilterValues,Len(Main.FilterValues)-1) As "FilterValues"
    From
    (
        Select distinct ST2.fieldID, 
        (
            Select ISNULL(ST1.[sortType], 'ASC') + ', ' AS [text()]
            From red.dbo.BS_ContentRequests_Tasks_User_Fields ST1
            JOIN dbo.BS_ContentRequests_Tasks_Fields_Options AS fl
            ON st1.fieldID = fl.fieldID
            Where ST1.fieldID = ST2.fieldID
            AND ST1.QID = @QID
            ORDER BY ST1.sortOrder ASC
            For XML PATH ('')
        ) [FilterValues]
        From red.dbo.BS_ContentRequests_Tasks_User_Fields ST2
        WHERE ST2.QID = @QID
    ) [Main]
) as b
ON a.fieldID = b.fieldID
WHERE a.QID = @QID

SELECT * FROM @sortStatements

-- Trim off the trailing comma
SELECT @sortClause = coalesce(@sortClause + ', ', '') + sortStatement
FROM @sortStatements

-- Set a variable to hold the whole WHERE logic which we will append later
SET @sort = (SELECT @sortClause)

SELECT @sort
```

The result set of `sortStatements` is below:

[image]

The final string that I use in my code (the result of `@sort`) is:

```
requestContentType ASC, dateRequested ASC, desiredCompletion ASC, dueDate ASC, requestID DESC, requestTitle ASC, requestType DESC, startDate ASC, requestStatus ASC, taskName ASC, requestorName ASC, requestorNTID ASC, taskStatus ASC, taskID ASC
```

The issue here is that those field names are not in the correct order that they should be in. In the middle statement, I have my order by clause which should be ordering it by the `sortOrder`

Here is the fieldName with its sort value, the order it should be in:

[image]

As you can see, the final output is in no particular order.. Is part of this query causing some type of sorting that is overriding my own? I have tried placing the `order by clause` in several areas but it doesn't change the final output.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the sortOrder to the generation of @sortStatements  THEN you can

```
SELECT @sortClause = coalesce(@sortClause + ', ', '') + sortStatement
FROM @sortStatements
Order by sortOrder
```

Comment: I've been bitten by that alligator

Comment: This answer depends on undocumented, but consistent, behavior in SQL Server. I'd suggest using `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`, as described [here](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/creating-a-comma-separated-list-with-for-xml-path-and-stuff/), for production code.

Comment: @HABO I certainly agree with you.  That said, I suspected OP was looking for a quick fix to his existing code/structure.